# Custom content type and views field rendering

Tags: views, theming

I have a template views-view-fields--services.tpl.php

I don't want to iterate over the array of fields as I know which each of them are in this case.

I want to simply:

```
<div>
  <?php echo $row->title; ?>
</div>
<div>
  <?php echo $row->image; ?>
</div>
```

Doesn't appear to be a higher level template which might have this context of data???

UPDATED CODE SAMPLE:

**views-view--services.tpl.php:**

```
<!-- Services -->
<section class="site-section section-details">
  <?php print $rows; ?>
</section>
```

**views-view-unformatted--services.tpl.php:**

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <alex>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </alex>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**views-view-fields--services.tpl.php:**

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>

  <?php /*print $field->class;*/ ?>
  <?php print $field->content; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Results in:

```
<section class="site-section section-details">
    <alex>

    <span>Entry #1</span>  

    <div><img src="http://temp.local/sites/foo/test.png" width="280" height="280" alt=""></div>  

    <div><p>Briefly describe which problems we can help with.</p>
</div>  
  </alex>
  <alex>

    <span>Entry #2</span>  

    <div><img src="http://temp.local/sites/foo/test2.png" width="280" height="280" alt=""></div>  

    <div><p>Quickly describe the services we offer or how our services can help?</p>
</div>  
  </alex>
</section>
```

Comment: Where is the markup between the <alex> tags coming from??? I want just the raw field data in a per-row context so I can simply write my required markup and echo each field (custom fields but I know what they are

Comment: In your view you probably need to strip the html tags as they are rendered by default in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [views-view-field.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-field.tpl.php/7). It' not used by default views, but available as a template override.

**Edit:** In [views-view-fields.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-fields.tpl.php/7) you can also use `$fields['my_field_name']->content;` to access individual fields, but this will give you the fields default markup as well. The raw values can be accessed with `$fields['my_field_name']->raw` but those values must be proper sanitized before printing.

Comment: I've tried that but VIEWS are still producing markup?!?! I've update my post with templates and code

Comment: @Alex Did you see the slight difference? I'm not relating to [views-view-fields.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-field.tpl.php/7)

Comment: I think I did but both fields and field are called once for each field...I want to use a template one step higher and basically output all 4 or five fields at once in the grid markup I have in place, if that makes any sense?

Comment: @Alex I have updated the answer, does this help now?

Comment: Yes it might...I dumped the $row variable in the context of views-view-field.tpl.php and this has all the info but if I can use $fields['name']->content thats even better :)